# Is there a word meaning "awardtion"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have completed a project, and am awaiting an award (I certainly qualify for it) and want to express that as part of my 6th form application. How can I express this? Of course *"awaiting awardtion"* is not correct, so what can I say that would express this?

Comment: This phrasing has no detail for the reader. Give more specific detail, and make it redundant in the process: did you *win/qualify for* the award and are waiting for an official listing/ceremony? Did you *compete for* it and are awaiting a decision? These and others are different scenarios which can fall under the very vague phrase *"waiting for an award"*

Comment: Done. Edited to clarify - the first scenario.

Comment: Is the award guaranteed or are you just extremely confident that in competing for the award you are the best and will most likely win?

Comment: Just say you have *[an] award **pending***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "awaiting commendation".

> **Commendation**/ kämənˈdāSH(ə)n/ *noun*: commendation; commendations (*plural noun*): praise. "*the film deserved the highest commendation*" **synonyms**: praise, congratulation, appreciation; acclaim, credit, recognition, respect, esteem, admiration, homage, tribute "*letters of commendation*" **an award involving special praise**. "the detectives received commendations for bravery"
>
> **Synonyms**: ***award***, accolade, prize, honor, honorable mention, mention, citation "*a commendation for bravery*"

from google.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rephrase it to sound more smoothly, but some examples from Google Books Corpus are 'awardshortlisted' after 'awardholder' or  'awardnominee', but  they appear to be far-fetched.

Here are some major results using

> [`award*] Google_Books_corpus_version_20130501_English_All_Nodes.txt.rip1gram.txt.sorted/

- 0,000,366 — award
- 0,000,296 — awards
- 0,000,206 — awarded
- 0,000,096 — awarding
- 0,000,056 — awardwinning
- 0,000,052 — awardable
- 0,000,050 — awardee
- 0,000,040 — awardees
- 0,000,018 — awardwinner
- 0,000,016 — awarders
- 0,000,006 — awardwinners
- 0,000,006 — awardbearing
- 0,000,004 — awardment
- 0,000,004 — awardgiving
- 0,000,004 — awardeth
- 0,000,002 — awardnominated
- 0,000,002 — awardings
- 0,000,002 — awardholders
- 0,000,002 — awardholder
- 0,000,002 — awardability